# Format datetime column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to delete dot and digits after dot in pandas datetime colums:

```
0   2020-01-05 21:58:15.030099
1   2020-01-09 09:15:01.286888
```

I write this code, but the result is the same (digits after dot):

```
ret.reg_dt = pd.to_datetime(ret.reg_dt, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

How can I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by seconds:

```
ret.reg_dt = ret.reg_dt.dt.floor('S')
print (ret)
               reg_dt
0 2020-01-05 21:58:15
1 2020-01-09 09:15:01
```